# Array_replace() function doesn't display the correct replaced value

Tags: php, arrays

Just need a little help here. Because I am creating a list of arrays. And I need to replace the value of an array using a condition. In validating the condition I don't have an error. But when I replace my array it doesn't replace. Sorry for my bad english. I hope you'd understand what I mean. Here's my code.

Here's my BASE array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [restaurant_id] => 1519
            [new_lat] => 14.63809
            [new_long] => 121.03242
            [date_updated] => 2013-11-14 18:53:20
        )

)
```

Now I will replace this array into this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [restaurant_id] => 1519
            [new_lat] => 14.63796
            [new_long] => 121.03278
            [date_updated] => 2013-11-15 06:54:32
        )

)
```

Now I used the array_replace();

Here's the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [restaurant_id] => 1519
            [new_lat] => 14.63809
            [new_long] => 121.03242
            [date_updated] => 2013-11-14 18:53:20
        )

    [restaurant_id] => 1519
    [new_lat] => 14.63796
    [new_long] => 121.03278
    [date_updated] => 2013-11-15 06:54:32
)
```

In my code for generating array:

```
 //THIS IS MY UPDATED ARRAY
        $data_add = array( 
            'restaurant_id' => $restaurant_id, 
            'new_lat' => $new_lat_entry, 
            'new_long' => $new_long_entry, 
            'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') 
        ); 

        $data = unserialize(file_get_contents('addresses.txt')); //THIS IS THE BASE ARRAY

//GET THE ID OF UPDATED ARRAY AND FIND IN THE BASE ARRAY - IF EXIST, UPDATE ONLY. IF NOT SIMPLY ADD

        $target = $data_add['restaurant_id'];

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

            $get_id = $data[$i]['restaurant_id'];

            if($get_id == $target){

                //if found update/delete specific row
                echo "found";

                $add_data = array();
                $add_data = array(
                    $i => $data_add
                );

                $new_array = array();
                $new_array = array_replace($data,$data_add);

            }else{

                //if not found add
                echo "not found";
                $data[] = $data_add; 

            }

        }
```

To display:

```
echo "<pre>";
            echo "BASE ARRAY<br />";
            print_r($data);
            echo "---------------------------------------------------------<br />";

            echo "NEW ARRAY<br />";
            print_r($add_data);
            echo "---------------------------------------------------------<br />";

            echo "REPLACED ARRAY<br />";
            print_r($new_array);
            echo "---------------------------------------------------------<br />";
```

Any idea where my code goes wrong? Please help me guys. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line -

```
$new_array = array_replace($data,$data_add);
```

to this -

```
$new_array = array_replace($data[0], $data_add);
```

$data_add isn't structured like you're portraying it above in the output. You have this code to create $data_add -

```
$data_add = array( 
    'restaurant_id' => $restaurant_id, 
    'new_lat' => $new_lat_entry, 
    'new_long' => $new_long_entry, 
    'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') 
);
```

If you actually output that array it would look like this -

```
Array
(
    [restaurant_id] => 1519
    [new_lat] => 14.63796
    [new_long] => 121.03278
    [date_updated] => 2013-11-15 06:54:32
)
```

So, you need to replace $data_add into $data[0], since you want to replace the zeroth index of $data.

Comment: Sir one more question. I fixed the displaying of new array. But in my text file it always add a new file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in my text file it always add a new file." Perhaps you can open a new question?